# Fundamental group and lifting criterion $3$-dimensional projective space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(0,0,0) \}$, $Y=X/\sim $ where $v \sim w \iff v= \pm w$, hence $Y \cong \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ 
Then $\pi_1(Y) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ since the deck associated to the covering has $2$ elements. 
Now let $f:S^1 \rightarrow Y$, $e^{2\pi it} \mapsto \pi((sin(\pi t),cos(\pi t),0))$ 
The question is whether there exists a map $g:S^1\rightarrow X$ with $\pi \circ g=f$ , where $\pi:  X \rightarrow Y$ is the quotient map.  
I think the idea is to use the lifting criterion which states that such a function exists if and only if $f_{*}(\pi_1(S^1))\subset G(\pi)=\pi_{*}(\pi_1(X))=\pi_{*}( \{1 \} )=\{1\}$. In other words if $f_{*}(\pi_1(S^1))$ is trivial. 
My thoughts are that for any element $\alpha_k$ in $\pi_1(S^1)$ we can conclude from the definition of $f$ that $[f \circ \alpha_k$ ] is a half circle and hence homotopic to a singleton point. Therefore $f_{*} \pi_1(S^1)$ is trivial and the condition is satisfied.
I would like to know whether my idea is correct and rigorous enough.

Comment: What does it mean for $[f \circ \alpha_k]$ to be a half-circle? Note that $f$ is injective. Can you have a continuous injection from a circle to a half-circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the idea is to use the lifting criterion ...

I am not so sure. Do you happen to know a theorem along the following lines:

> Let $\lambda\colon [0,1]\to Y$ be a path and $\pi\colon X\to Y$ a covering map and $p\in X$ a point such that $\lambda(0)=\pi(p)$, then there is a unique lift $\tilde\lambda\colon [0,1]\to X$ such that $\pi\circ\tilde\lambda=\lambda$ and $\tilde\lambda(0)=p$.

Then you can do something like the following:

Consider the path $F\colon[0,1]\to Y$ given by $F(t)=f(e^{2\pi it})$. Then there is a unique lift $\tilde F\colon [0,1]\to X$ given by $\tilde F(t)=(\sin(\pi t),\cos(\pi t),0)$. Now *if* there is a $g\colon S^1\to X$ such that $\pi\circ g=f$, we can consider the path $G\colon [0,1]\to X$ given by $G(t)=g(e^{2\pi it})$ which then satisfies $\pi\circ G=F$, i.e. $G$ is a lift of $F$! But $\tilde F$ is also a lift of $F$, so $G=\tilde F$ because lifts are unique. But $G(1)=g(e^{2\pi i})=G(0)$ whereas $\tilde F(1)=(\sin(\pi),\cos(\pi),0)\neq(\sin(0),\cos(0),0)=\tilde F(0)=G(0)$, so $\tilde F$ does not equal $G$, so such a $G$ does not exist.